# whoosh search query with converting '-' into AND

Tags: python, tokenize, whoosh

I'm trying to use whoosh to do text searches.

When I search for a string containing `-` (ex.: `'IGF-1R'`), it ends up searching for `'IGF'` AND `'1R'`, hence not treating it as a single string.

Any idea why?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
class MyFuzzyTerm(FuzzyTerm):
     def __init__(self, fieldname, text, boost=1.0, maxdist=1, prefixlength=2, constantscore=True):
          super(MyFuzzyTerm, self).__init__(fieldname, text, boost, maxdist, prefixlength, constantscore)

with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    qp = QueryParser("gene", schema=ix.schema, termclass=MyFuzzyTerm)
    q = qp.parse('IGF-1R')
```

q returns:

```
And([MyFuzzyTerm('gene', 'igf', boost=1.000000, maxdist=1, prefixlength=2), MyFuzzyTerm('gene', '1r', boost=1.000000, maxdist=1, prefixlength=2)])
```

I'd like it to be:

```
MyFuzzyTerm('gene', 'igf-1r', boost=1.000000, maxdist=1, prefixlength=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separating text into words is the job of tokenizer, I usually use the `whoosh.analysis.SpaceSeparatedTokenizer()` but for your case the tokenizer is separating based on space and dash.
So I bet you are using the `whoosh.analysis.CharsetTokenizer(charmap)` with (space, dash) within `charmap` or the `whoosh.analysis.RegexTokenizer(expression=<_sre.SRE_Pattern object>, gaps=False)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll give it a try.